# Como importar a lista de contatos de emails do Hotmail/Outlook?

Tags: javascript, email, importação

Recentemente tive que fazer a importação da lista de contatos de mails do Hotmail/Outlook dos usuários de meu aplicativo, e apresento abaixo uma das formas que você pode proceder caso também precise implementar esse recurso em seu sistema no lado cliente (FrontEnd) via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Passo 1. Crie um aplicativo Windows Live no "Microsoft account Developer Center" para obter seu Client ID e Client Secret

Acesse a página [Microsoft account Developer Center](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index) e crie um novo aplicativo clicando no link "Create Application".

[image: Criando um novo aplicativo Windows Live]

Informe o nome e idioma que você deseja dar ao seu aplicativo e clique no botão *I Accept* para indicar que você leu e concorda com os termos de uso da Microsoft para a criação de aplicativos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em **Basic Information** forneça as demais informações básicas de seu aplicativo, tais como a imagem da logomarca e URLs dos termos de serviço e política de uso de seu aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba **API Settings**, preencha os campos da seguinte maneira:

- *Mobile or desktop client app:* No
- *Target domain:* deixe em branco
- *Restrict JWT issuing:* No
- *Root domain:* este campo será preenchido automaticamente quando você informar o próximo campo.
- *Redirect URLs:* informe aqui a URL da página para a qual o Windows Live irá redirecionar seus usuários após eles confirmarem que desejam permitir ao seu aplicativo acessar a lista de contatos de emails deles.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloque o seguinte código em sua página de redirecionamento (no caso do exemplo, seria a página www.meusite.com.br/redirecionamento.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Página de Redirecionamento</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Este script irá repassar a resposta de autorização oauth para a página que fez a solicitação de obtenção da lista de contatos. -->
        <script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Acesse a aba **App Settings** para visualizar as credenciais ( Client ID e Client Secret) que seu aplicativo deverá utilizar para se conectar com a API do Windows Live, o qual será o nosso próximo passo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 2. Exemplo de Código de Importação da Lista de Contatos de Emails

Faça a importação da biblioteca Windows Live na página em que você deseja importar a lista de contatos de emails de seu usuário, da seguinte forma:

```
<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

Inicialize o SDK Live JavaScript executando o código abaixo e substituindo os valores de `client_id` e `redirect_uri` com os valores de seu próprio aplicativo:

```
WL.init({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID_DE_SEU_APLICATIVO',
    redirect_uri: 'www.meusite.com.br/redirecionamento.html',
    scope: ["wl.basic", "wl.contacts_emails"],
    response_type: "token"
});
```

Crie um botão para executar a importação dos contatos:

```
<input type="button" onclick="importeContatosDoHotmail();" value="Importar Contatos" />
```

Implemente a função de importação dos contatos do Hotmail/Outlook como no código a seguir:

```
function importeContatosDoHotmail() {
    WL.login({
        scope: ["wl.basic", "wl.contacts_emails"]
    }).then(function (response) {
        WL.api({
            path: "me",
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function (responseMe) {
            // Dados do perfil do usuário.
            console.log(responseMe);

            WL.api({
                 path: "me/contacts",
                 method: "GET"
            }).then(function (responseMeContacts) {
                // Lista de contatos de emails do usuário.
                console.log(responseMeContacts.data);
            },
            function (responseFailed) {
                // Motivo da falha de obtenção da lista de contatos do usuário.
                console.log(responseFailed);
                }
            );
        },
        function (responseFailed) {
            // Motivo da falha de obtenção dos dados do perfil do usuário.
            console.log(responseFailed);
        }
    );
 },
 function (responseFailed) {
    // Motivo da falha de autenticação com o Windows Live.
    console.log(responseFailed);
 });
```

}